# GridBagLayout - I seem to have less columns than I specified, but why?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I am trying to make my frame setup not look ugly, so I decided to dive into layouts.

`GridBagLayout` seemed the most versatile, so I am experimenting a little with it, in order to understand it. My problem is, that even though I have 3 components in 3 columns, for some reason, the first two components are put in the same column. Maybe I don't understand it, but I have thought it over 20 times and it doesn't really makes sense to me. Please help.

Here is some code:

```java
// Frame Setup
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("GridBagLayout_Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        frame.setLocation(550, 250);
        frame.setSize(800, 550);

        JPanel startScreen = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        startScreen.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.weighty = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

        JButton colorbutton = new JButton("Color");
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.gridx = 2;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        colorbutton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 30));
        startScreen.add(colorbutton, gbc);

        JLabel game_name = new JLabel("LABEL");
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 3;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        game_name.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
        game_name.setOpaque(true);
        game_name.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 30));
        startScreen.add(game_name, gbc);

        JButton start = new JButton("START");
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        start.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 30));
        startScreen.add(start, gbc);

        // Show Results
        frame.add(startScreen);
        frame.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> even though I have 3 components in 3 columns, for some reason, the first two components are put in the same column

Actually from the GridBagLayout point of view you only have two columns.

```
gbc.gridwidth = 3;
```

When you use the `gridWidth` constraint you are saying you don't have a specific column because it will occupy the space of 3 columns (assuming you actually have 3 columns which you don't). Since you only have 2 components with a gridwidth of 1, you really only have 2 columns.

That is the first column doesn't have a unique width (because the only component added to the first column spans multiple columns), so where should column 2 start?

To demonstrate this, change your code to only use the `gridx` and `gridy` constraints.

Then you will see the 3 components in 3 columns on 3 separate lines.

Next, add back the:

```
gbc.gridwidth = 3;
```

for the "label".

Then you will see all 3 components in a single column. This is because the gridwidth of 3 will also be used for the "start" button. So effectively the "label" and "start" components don't have a unique column, so only the "color" has a defined column, so you have a grid with a single column.

Next, add back the:

```
gbc.gridwidth = 1;
```

for the "start" button.

Then you will see two columns for the buttons and the label will span the two columns. This is because the "start" and "color" has unique columns and the "label" can only span 2 columns (even though you asked it to span 3 columns).

I'm not sure the exact layout you are trying to accomplish, so I can't give a suggested solution, but hopefully you understand why you really only have 2 columns, not 3.

Note as a hack you can add a dummy component in the first column, then the label can span 3 columns. The dummy component would be something like:

```
    JLabel filler = new JLabel("");
    gbc.gridheight = 1;
    gbc.gridwidth = 1;
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    game_name.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 30));
    startScreen.add(filler, gbc);
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that an enlarged component doesn't count towards the amount of columns! Adding an "invisible" dummy component did the trick. :)

Answer (score 0):

GridBagLayouts and GridBagConstrains are work like an excel sheet. There are columns and rows where you can place the components in a horizontal and vertical manner. You can also merge the layout and so on.

As I understand your case, you have 3 components which you want to put in 3 columns.

The location of your component in the layout is determined by the **gridx** and **gridy** values of the particular components GridBagConstraints

So in your case, you should have the following values for each component;

for **colorbutton**, gridx = 0 and gridy = 0

for **game_name**, gridx = 1 and gridy = 0

for **start**, gridx = 2 and gridy = 0

So all 3 components will be distributed in the same row (gridy) and 3 different columns (gridx)

**gridwidth** determines whether you are merging any columns or not. In your case, you used gridwidth as 3 for the game_name label. So you are merging 3 columns for this label.

because of that, your gridx values should also change to support the merge as follows;

for **colorbutton**, gridx = 0 and gridy = 0

for **game_name**, gridx = 1 and gridy = 0

for **start**, gridx = 4 and gridy = 0

You can have the same output by changing the **gridwidth** as 1 with my first x and y values

Following will be the corrected code;

```
// Frame Setup
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("GridBagLayout_Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        frame.setLocation(550, 250);
        frame.setSize(800, 550);

        JPanel startScreen = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        startScreen.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.weighty = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

        JButton colorbutton = new JButton("Color");
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.gridx = 0; // change
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        colorbutton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 30));
        startScreen.add(colorbutton, gbc);

        JLabel game_name = new JLabel("LABEL");
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 3;
        gbc.gridx = 1; // change
        gbc.gridy = 0; // change
        game_name.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
        game_name.setOpaque(true);
        game_name.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 30));
        startScreen.add(game_name, gbc);

        JButton start = new JButton("START");
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.gridx = 4; // change
        gbc.gridy = 0; // change
        start.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 30));
        startScreen.add(start, gbc);

        // Show Results
        frame.add(startScreen);
        frame.setVisible(true);
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks, however, for the sake of a nice Layout I don't want it all to be in a single row. I did get a grip on how to do it though, so no worries. ;)